# Updating Minecraft X-Box 360 - will a save game against the tutorial world be safe?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

By X-box 360 (for reasons that don't matter) has not been connected to the internet for awhile.

My son has spent some time playing Minecraft (from the disk edition, 2013 -- TU11?) and his save game is in the tutorial world.

I understand that once I get the X-box back connected to the net it will update and that the tutorial world will be different (TU19). Will his saved game be safe?

Comment: I would copy the world and then open it. That way you will know if any new biomes will appear. Also, [this site](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-xbox-360-edition/mcx360-discussion/2007503-how-to-back-up-world) may help you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, any worlds that existed before the latest update will still be there, including tutorial worlds (if you saved in the tutorial world, since you said your son saved in the old tutorial world).

This also includes other worlds that have been played before an update.